# python: экспоненциальный формат записи чисел в json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

есть массив чисел

```
arr = [300, 5000, 3.7e11]
```

подскажите как создать json где числе будут в виде **чисел** (а не строк) в экспоненциальном формате, т.е.

```
[3e2, 5e3, 3.7e11]
```

P.S.

чуть более сложнее, а если мне надо чтобы

`300` было `3.0e2`, но `300.123` было `3.00123e2`?

Comment: Разве что вручную форматировать каждое число и собирать json из кусков как строку

Comment: Т.е. какой-то такой костыль (правда еще + перед e добавляется): `j = "[{}]".format(", ".join(map("{:.02g}".format, arr)))`

Comment: Зачем? JSON - формат хранения и передачи данных. Каждое число записывается туда с максимальной точностью. Если есть несколько способов без ущерба точности, выбирается какой-то. Нет цели чтобы это хорошо выглядело для человека. Зачем тогда?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, чтобы более компактно записывать числа - у меня много 6-10 значных чисел, которые легко сворачиваются в `x.xex` пятизначные

Comment: "чтобы более компактно записывать числа" - какую проблему вы решаете, упрощение чтения человеком или уменьшения трафика/занимаемого объема?

Comment: Для уменьшения трафика наверняка сжатие 
трафика гораздо больше даст, такие текстовые данные должны отлично сжиматься старым добрым семейством LZ алгоритмов (zip).

Comment: В общем, это похоже на ["проблему XY"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/1365).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать fjson

```
string = fjson.dumps({"x":arr}, float_format=".2e", indent=2, separators=(", ", ": "))
```

результатом будет:

```
{
  "x": [
    300,
    5000,
    3.70e+11
  ]
}
```

Comment: Модуль конечно интересный, но считать что любой json - это словарь, это они конечно "хорошо" придумали.

Comment: Ну и при использовании не типовых библиотек надо бы давать ссылку на описание этой библиотеки. А то бывает по нескольку библиотек с одним названием часто, поди разбери.